# Приложение на android 11 переписать под android 10

Tags: android, android-sdk

Случайно написал приложение на 11 андроид, хотя надо было на 10, как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Поправьте в манифесте minSDK на нужную

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Возможно, также, что Вы случайно использовали api, которое доступно только в 11 андроид, тут уже придется искать замены и переписывать